# Editing with Map Topology performance in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: editing, file-geodatabase, performance, topology, arcgis-pro

I have been working on some basic cartography for a fantasy world I am creating, and ArcMap 10.4 was being slow on editing some of the large island polygons I am creating. I figured that as all I am doing is basic editing I would try ArcGIS Pro for speed and to be able to use my 16 gb of RAM. I love how responsive the program is generally, but editing is frustrating. When I click on "Move" to move a feature, for example, the program doesn't allow me to actually move or rotate any feature until several minutes of the mouse cursor with the spinning wheel. All I have is a basic polygon layer for islands and a basemap. Why is it being so slow?

It's in a File Geodatabase. They do have large amounts of vertices because several of the polygons are the size of large islands several hundreds of miles across. I turned off Map Topology and things seem to have sped up a lot -- I bet that's the problem!

Comment: Have you tried turning off snapping to see if that helps as a test?

Comment: This is, as you suspected, the topology graph at work. We'll look at a few things to improve the experience.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try this at ArcGIS Pro 1.3?

Answer (score 1):

I spend a lot of time working on fantasy maps, currently I am working on several large shapefiles/geodatabases which in combination cover the whole of northern Africa. I have had a lot of trouble running that much data in ArcGIS Pro, but ArcMap on the other hand, gives me no trouble at all working on such a large dataset. I would suggest working with ArcMap rather than ArcGIS Pro if you do not have any need for a 3D viewer.